# Sending html Form data to sender's email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a form in html and with the php script trying to send it to the email however it's not working. Can you please check where I'm wrong?

Whenever I click on send button, it starts showing the php code instead of sending the email to the given email.

```html
HTML
----


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title> <!-- Include CSS file here -->
<link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1> Form Request </h1>

<form name="contactform"  action="email.php"  method="post">

  Name:  <input type="text" name="full_name"><br \><br \>
  Id:   <input type="text" id="id"><br \><br \>
  Email id: <input type="email" email="email"><br \><br \>
  <a href="Form_IP.pdf" download>Download Blank Form </a> <br \><br \><br \>
  Upload Filled Form<br \><br \>
  
  <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="resellerfile"></p>
    
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
                var file = x.files[i];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (x.value == "") {
            txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
            txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("resellerfile").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
<br \><br \>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">



</form>
</body>
</html>

========================
```

```html
    <?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
  
  //Email information
  $admin_email = "xyx@submit.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $id, "From:" . $email);
  
  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }
  
  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Name:  <input type="text" name="full_name"><br \><br \>
  Id:   <input type="text" id="id"><br \><br \>
  Email id: <input type="email" email="email"><br \><br \>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: well its because you are trying to run a php file without a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing you raw php because php scripts can not be executed directly by the browser, `php scripts` are processed and executed by server and then html response is sent to the browser.

So, you need to host the php script on a server remotely or locally.
if you want to set up a server locally on your system try installing XAMP or WAMP.

Refer to the link below.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using Xampp's htdocs folder to see if it's responding?